# Approach for large data set for reporting

Tags: amazon-s3, architecture, report, tableau-api, matillion

I am having 220 millions of raw files in AWS s3 which I considering to merge all into a single file which estimate around 10 terabyte. The merge file will be serve as a fact table but in file format for reporting purposes for the audit.

The raw files are source data from an application. If there is any new data changes to the application, the contain of the file will be change.

I would like to ask is anybody come across this end to end process for this user case?

s3--> ETL (file merging)--> s3 --> reporting (tableau)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't personally tried it, but this is kind of what Athena is made for... Skipping your ETL process, and querying directly from the files.  Is there a reason you are dumping this all into a single file instead of keeping it dispersed?  Rewriting a 10TB file over and over again is very expensive and time consuming... I'd personally at least investigate keeping the files 1-1 with the source files.

1. Create a s3 trigger that fires when a file is rewritten on s3
2. [Create a Lambda that creates your "audit ready" report files on s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)
3. Use [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) to query those report files
4. [Tableau connector to Athena](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/examples_amazonathena.htm) for your reports